# How to close an external application using c#

Tags: c#, process

Im trying to be close the calculator when the user press's a key on the key board. But p.kill and p.CloseMainWindow doesn't kill the calculator, only the shell which is executed.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c calc ";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to kill Calc");
Console.ReadKey();
p.CloseMainWindow();

p.Kill();
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use the shell (cmd) but run the calc process directly. Setting Process.StartInfo.FileName to "calc" should do it (assuming calc.exe is on the system path).

Comment: So you have to validate this answer... (I may say that a little bit too late)

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the Calculator process and kill it. There are actually two processes created: one for the `cmd` and the other for Calculator. You are killing only the first one.

The other solution is to start the Calculator directly, without using `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

because your process is not the calc.exe process but the command prompt which executes the calc.

to find a process by name and kill it, you should use GetProcessByName,

see an example here: [C# Process Process.GetProcessesByName, Kill Process and Exit Event](http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-process-processgetprocessesbyname.html)